# Android DataBinding error. Could not find accessor

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my app:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor java.lang.String.giftRecipientName redacted.xml loc:182:63 - 182:93 ****\ data binding error ****
```

I have an Order object which looks like this:

```
public class Order {
    public Address address;
    // unrelated fields and methods
}
```

The nested Address object looks like this:

```
public class Address {
    public String addressLine1;
    public String addressLine2;
    public String giftRecipientName;
    public Boolean isGift;
}
```

In my .xml I am doing the following:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="order" type="example.redacted.models.Order"/>
    </data>
    // widgets and whatnot
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gift_recipientTV"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text='@{order.address.isGift ?  order.address.giftRecipientName : "" }'/>
```

Lastly in my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RedactedBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.redacted, container, false);
    dataBinding.setOrder(_order);
    return dataBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After hours of trial and error it seems that Android data-binding looks for getters *before* it looks at public fields. My Order object had a helper method called getAddress

```
public class Order {
    public Address address;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address.addressLine1 + address.addressLine2;
    }
}
```

The binder was calling that method instead of accessing the public Address field. I put the getAddress method inside the Address object (where it probably should have been to begin with) and the app compiled.

Answer (score 9):

> Android DataBinding error. Could not find accessor

- As this error tells, binding needs `accessor` or `getter` to work and also `setter` if you use **[two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38982604/6891563)**.
- So always put `getter` & `setter` in your model class.

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer and must be upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was accessing a kotlin object's property from xml:

```
object CurrentUser {
    // ...
    var userTeams: Map<String, String> = //...
    // ...
}
```

```xml
<Button
   android:text="@{CurrentUser.userTeams.get("id")}" />
```

but as data binding uses Java, it can't access a Kotlin object directly, so I changed it to:

```xml
<Button
   android:text="@{CurrentUser.INSTANCE.userTeams.get("id")}" />
```

And it works!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, My `ViewModel` has a variable name starting with m and it was creating a problem

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<SomeClass> mTask; //Chaning the variable name to task and it's getter name to getTask worked for me
    //...code left for brevity
    public LiveData<SomeClass> getmTask() {
        return mTask;
    }
}
```

I changed the variable name `mTask` to `task` and it's getter name `getmTask` to `getTask` and it worked for me.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<SomeClass> task;
    //...code left for brevity
    public LiveData<SomeClass> getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

And In my xml file I was able to access it

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@{viewmodel.task.title}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your Layout file and ViewModel class. A variable name should be the same in both files.just like:

In ViewModel class:

```
MutableLiveData<String> emailId = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

In Layout files:

```
<EditText
     ........
      android:text="@={loginVM.emailId}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please to change the parameter values private to public its will working

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason for this can be just **mistyped variable names**.
In my case, I have written

```
android:text="@={viewModel.authPhone.Phone}"
```

instead of

```
android:text="@={viewModel.authPhone.phone}"
```

You don't have to write or override getter and setter for the data class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the fact that I was using the wrong object all together. I was using:

```
<variable
  name="searchResults"
  type=".SearchResults" />
```

Instead of:

```
<variable
  name="searchResults"
  type=".SearchViewModel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same as @Sanjeev. The class instance variable began with "m" (mUsername). However, the problem is not the name of the instance variable.  The problem is the name of the getter.  When I changed the getter from `getmUserName()` to `getUserName()`, it worked.  I don't understand why the "m" in the  getter name caused a problem.

Comment: [mNo](https://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar problem and spent a couple of hours on it..
We tried to implement `StateFlow` instead of `LiveData` and had a couple of `Could not find accessor` errors...

Our solution:

- Upgrade Gradle Plugin from 4.2.2 to 7.* (JDK 1.8 -> JDK 11)

Answer (score 0):

late to the party, it may be that a particular variable is used in another Model class as its own class file. Search and see and if you can rename it. I had this issue.